# warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, gcc-warning

When I am running my program with `gcc -Wall`, I am getting

```
warning: array subscript has type ‘char’
```

Please help me where its going wrong. The warning says its at line 20:7 & 21:7. How can I get rid of the warning?

```
/* This program asks the user for 2 words and tells the user if those 2 words
   are anagrams even if its capitalized or not. The maximum length of letters
   is 20.  */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int anagram(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    // Create two count arrays and initialize all values as 0
    int numOfChar = 20;
    char count1[123] = {0};
    char count2[123] = {0};
    int i;

    /* For each character in the strings, it increases in
       the corresponding count array */
    for (i = 0; str1[i] && str2[i];  i++)
    {
        count1[str1[i]]++;
        count2[str2[i]]++;
    }

    // If both strings are different lengths.
    if (str1[i] || str2[i]) // If one statement is true
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Compares count arrays
    for (i = 0; i < numOfChar; i++)
    {
        if (count1[i] != count2[i]) // If dont equal to eachother
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 1;

}

// Construct function
void construct()
{
    int anagram(char*,char*); // Variables
    char str[20], str1[20];
    int check = 0;

    printf("Please enter the first word: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("Please enter the second word: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);


    check=anagram(str, str1);
    if (check==1)
    {               // If true then print
        printf("%s is an anagram of %s\n", str, str1);
    }
    else
    {               // If false then print
        printf("%s is NOT an anagram of %s\n", str, str1);
    }

    return ;
}

// Main function
int main()
{
  construct(); // Calls construct function
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can cast the `char`s to `int` or `size_t`

Comment: quick dirty fix `count1[(int)str1[i]]++;`

Comment: I've edited your title. The title is an error message, but you changed it to mixed case. Both C and gcc command-line options are case-sensitive; `Char` is distinct from `char`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the strings may contain characters from non-us character set (any encoding besides us-ascii).

Which are represented as negative values. I think accessing array with negative index is not exactly what you expect to have.

Handling that as:

```
    count1[(unsigned char)str1[i]]++;
    count2[(unsigned char)str2[i]]++;
```

Would suppress the warning, but will still have out of bounds issue.

Adding the following check into for loop would terminate the loop in case character value is totally unexpected:

```
 str1[i] && str2[i] &&
 (unsigned char)str1[i] < countof(count1) &&
 (unsigned char)str2[i] < countof(count2)
```

Where `countof` is defined as:

```
#define countof(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])
```

Comment: The situation is more nuanced than this. On some platforms, plain `char` is a signed type (as you describe) and on other platforms it is an unsigned type. So, when the characters are outside the 7-bit ASCII range, you can't be sure whether you'll be indexing positive or negative values. So, a negative index is (indeed) a problem, but not all compilers run into the problem. But that's why the warning appears (on both types of platform, AFAIK), and also why the `(unsigned char)` cast is necessary (or an equivalent operation). It not only fixes the warning; it ensures you access the right data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The correct fix is to use `unsigned char *` everywhere you can.  The cast can, in theory, destroy the bitwise representation of a character. Suppose that the character has the bit pattern `10000001` (code 129), but `signed char` is represented as 8 bit sign-magnitude: `10000001` thus has the value -1. But `(unsigned char) -1` will produce `11111111`, which is 255, and not 129.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is giving you the warning about indexing for lines 20 and 21 which are

```
count1[str1[i]]++;
count2[str2[i]]++;
```

and the suspicious indexing comes from the function arguments.

```
int anagram(char* str1, char* str2)
```

Note that they point to a `char` type, which is signed by default. So if one element of the array you are using to index into `count1[]` has a value in the range `0x80` to `0xFF` that will cause a negative index to be used, which obviously is not in range of the array `count1[]`.

Although `count1[]` and `count2[]` only have 123 elements, so you are not expecting indices that will *actually* be negative numbers, it is still better to make the arrays passed `unsigned char`, so the function will be declared as

```
int anagram(unsigned char* str1, unsigned char* str2)
```

Then you will always get a positive index. As for the warning, MSVC doesn't give me one, but if you then cast the index to `int` as commented below your question, that should take care of it.

Comment: char is not unsigned by default.   It is implementation defined whether char is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Rob that's true. I should have said that on my implementation `char` is signed by default.

Answer (score 0):

The reason compilers give such a warning is that, often, when doing `x[index]` where `index` is a char type, is often a programming error.

If it is what you intend, simply force the conversion to an `int`.   For example, in your code,  `count1[(int)str1[i]]++;`.

Bear in mind that a char that prints the numeral `'1'` does not have a value equal numerically to `1`.   Forgetting that, and assuming it does, is one of the common errors that the compiler warning will pick up.